# How to write to parent directory of jmeter test using jmeter's 'save response to a file' node

Tags: jmeter

Herro,

I know that if you use '~/' in the filename prefix then that will get you to the location of the jmeter test. What I want is to write the file to the parent directory of the test file. Is there a way to accomplish this. Basically the goal is to have the test be able to dynamically write the file to the parent directory of the test file (wherever it happens to be)

Answer (score 1):

figured it out. you use '..' to go up a directory (duh) so if you wanted to name your file tendervittles and put it in the parent directory of the test file it would be

~/../tendervittles